Generalized linear independence of trigonometric polynomials
Consider the following generalized linear combination of trigonometric polynomials
$$
P_{a,v}(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k + i\langle v_k,t\rangle) e^{i \langle x_k, t\rangle}
$$
with $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $v_k,t,x_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with pairwise distinct $x_k$.
I need the following statement
$$
P_{a,v} = 0 \implies a = 0 \text{ and }v=0.
$$
This is very similar to linear independence of the trigonometric polynomials, only that the coefficients $c_k(t) = a_k + i\langle v_k, t\rangle$ depend on $t$.
This would be the final step in a longer proof (cf. https://mathoverflow.net/a/469539/122659).

Take derivatives wr $x_k$ and see what happens

@Conrad Taking the derivative of $x_k$ in the direction of $w$ results in
$$
(a_k+i\langle v_k, t\rangle)i\langle w, t\rangle e^{i\langle x_k, t\rangle}
$$
What am I supposed to see in that? I mean if $w\perp t$ then the derivative is zero, but is that a surprise?

I meant $t_k$; since $P(t)$ is identically zero, these are also zero and you get more relations of the same type (think of the original $P(t)$ as one linear equation in many finitely many unknowns $a_k,v_k$ for each $t$; differentiation preserves the linear character in those two variable as you multiply only by $x_k$ components; the putting $t=0$ after taking enough derivatives should allow to conclude the result by linear algebra I think - that's what I would look at first anyway; another tack is to treat this as a power series in many variables and use results in that area

Then you get that a power series in $d$ variables is identically zero for all real components $t$ and then writing it as $\sum c_at^a$ where $a$ is multi index and $t^a$ the appropriate homogeneous polymomial in the components of $t$ compute the $c_a$;which are of course all zero though it still comes down to partial derivatives

@Conrad thanks! I will try

The solution is almost infuriatingly simple if we use the Fourier transform
$$
\mathcal{F}[f](t) := \int f(y)e^{i\langle y,t\rangle} dy
$$
Then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}[\delta_x](t)
&= e^{i\langle x, t\rangle}\\
\mathcal{F}[D_v\delta_x](t)
&= -i\langle v, t\rangle e^{i\langle x, t\rangle}
\end{align*}
where $D_v\delta_x$ is the directional derivative of $\delta_x$ in the sense of distributions. This implies
$$
\mathcal{F}\Bigl[ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\delta_{x_k} - D_{v_k}\delta_{x_k}\Bigr](t) = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k + i\langle v_k, t\rangle)e^{i\langle x_k, t\rangle} = 0
$$
Which then implies by linearity of the Fourier transform
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\delta_{x_k} - D_{v_k}\delta_{x_k} = 0.
$$
But since the $x_k$ are distinct, the only way this distribution can be zero, is if the $a_k$ and $v_k$ are all zero.

A slightly more extensive explanation
Let $\phi$ be a test function. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathcal{F}[D_vf], \phi\rangle
&= \langle D_v f, \mathcal{F}[\phi]\rangle
\\
&= -\langle f, D_v \mathcal{F}[\phi]\rangle
\\
&= - \int f(t) \int i\langle v, x\rangle e^{i\langle t, x\rangle}
\phi(x)dx dt
\\
&= -i \int \langle v, x\rangle\int f(t)e^{i\langle t, x\rangle}dt \phi(x)dx
\\
&= \langle -i\langle v, \cdot\rangle\mathcal{F}[f], \phi\rangle 
\end{align*}
This shows
$$
\mathcal{F}[D_vf] = -i\langle v, \cdot\rangle\mathcal{F}[f]
$$
Thus
$$
\mathcal{F}[D_v \delta_x] 
= -\langle v, \cdot\rangle\mathcal{F}[\delta_x]
= -\langle v, \cdot\rangle e^{i\langle x,\cdot\rangle}
$$
Furthermore we have
$$
\langle D_v\delta_x, \phi\rangle = - \langle\delta_x, D_v\phi\rangle = - D_v\phi(x)
$$
So the requirement that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\delta_{x_k} - D_{v_k}\delta_{x_k} = 0
$$
in the sense of distributions implies that for all test functions $\phi$
$$
\Bigl\langle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\delta_{x_k} - D_{v_k}\delta_{x_k}, \phi\Bigr\rangle
= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \phi(x_k) + D_{v_k}\phi(x_k)
$$
Since the $x_k$ are distinct and finite, there is a minimum distance so we can simply use bump functions which are centered on some $x_{j}$ to get
$$
\phi(x_k) = \begin{cases}
1 & k=j\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
and have the derivatives all be zero at the $x_k$. This shows that $a_j$ is zero. For the $v_k$ we similarly construct functions which have a particular derivative at $x_j$ and are zero at all the other $x_k$.
